Unexpected Identifier $: QwikJs
I've written some code to display a 3D model using Qwik and Three.js. Unfortunately, I'm encountering an error that indicates an "unexpected identifier '$'." I suspect this issue might be related to scope, especially considering there's a web worker involved. However, I'm not entirely certain. Any assistance or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
import { component$, useOnDocument, $ } from '@builder.io/qwik';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import type { GLTF } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

export const Robot = component$(() => {
  useOnDocument('qinit', $(() => {

... (other code)

    async function loadModel() {
      const threeJS = await fetchScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js');
      const gltfLoaderJS = await fetchScript('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mrdoob/three.js@r128/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js');

      const workerCode = `
        const threeJS = \`${threeJS}\`;
        const gltfLoaderJS = \`${gltfLoaderJS}\`;

        eval(threeJS);
        eval(gltfLoaderJS);

        const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

        self.onmessage = function(event) {
          const { url } = event.data;
          loader.load(url, function(gltf) {
            self.postMessage({ type: 'model', data: gltf });
          }, undefined, function(error) {
            self.postMessage({ type: 'error', data: error });
          });
        };
      `;

      const blob = new Blob([workerCode], { type: 'application/javascript' });
      const worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
      worker.postMessage({ url: '/bane10-20.gltf' });

      worker.onmessage = function(event: MessageEvent) {
        const { type, data } = event.data;

        if (type === 'model') {
          const gltf: GLTF = data;
          const model = gltf.scene;

          model.traverse((object: THREE.Object3D) => {
            if ((object as THREE.Mesh).isMesh) {
              const mesh = object as THREE.Mesh;
              if (!mesh.material) {
                mesh.material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: 0x555555 });
              }
            }
          });

          scene.add(model);
          document.body.removeChild(loadingDiv);
        } else if (type === 'error') {
          console.error('An error occurred while loading the GLTF model:', data);
          document.body.removeChild(loadingDiv);
        }
      };
    }

    function animate() {
      if (renderer) {
        frameId = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
      }
    }

    function onResize() {
      if (renderer && camera) {
        const width = container.clientWidth;
        const height = container.clientHeight;
        renderer.setSize(width, height);
        camera.aspect = width / height;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', onResize);

    init();

    return () => {
      if (frameId) cancelAnimationFrame(frameId);
      if (renderer) {
        renderer.dispose();
        if (renderer.domElement.parentElement) {
          renderer.domElement.parentElement.removeChild(renderer.domElement);
        }
      }
      document.body.removeChild(loadingDiv);
      window.removeEventListener('resize', onResize);
    };
  }));

  return <div></div>;
});


I don't use this framework, but the error may be related to how you load the model (and perhaps the import).
Try changing to
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

//...

const loader = new GLTFLoader();

OFFICIAL
Also note that you are using r128. Therefore, it is also worth tracking changes in versions to avoid potential errors.
Migration Guide
